# Infrastructure web application and database relationship

Tags: .net, database, infrastructure

For simplicity, let's say this is restricted to MSSQL and .NET. I have 20+ .Net applications (webform and MVC w/wo Entity FrameWork). I also have 15+ Databases. My goal is to build some what of a infrastructure application and DB diagram. This will help determine what table/database is tied to certain web application. I have scourged the internet and haven't seen anything similar (maybe I wasn't using the right words). Hopefully, someone has tackled this and would provide some guidelines and hints.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Without knowing what internal coding standards and db frameworks you used it is not possible for anyone to say. It will come down to you creating an app that parses your code and designer files for db object names. You might have to add a lot of custom logic or even DB object parsing, example: stored procedures probably do something to tables and you need to show what tables. You will have to parse code first mappings, edmx mappings, hard coded sql strings, sql strings in resource files, sql built in webform designers, maybe even more like dynamic sql creation. It will also be error prone.

Comment: The question was abstract and generic for a reason. I wanted to know if there's any solution out there regardless of db frameworks and coding standards. I'm sure this is a common problem and wanted to see if anyone has done anything.